# zend2 insert into collection/database

Tags: forms, collections, insert, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have some problem with colection in zf2 and doctryne.

Problem: I add some client and need have some multiselect.

ClientEntity

```
/**
* @ORM\MappedSuperclass
*/
class Client {
...
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Module\Model\Job")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="job_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $job;
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SomeOption", mappedBy="job", cascade= {"persist", "remove"})
 * */
protected $someOption;
...
public function __construct() {
    $this->someOption= new ArrayCollection();
}
```

OptionEntity

```
/**
* @ORM\MappedSuperclass
*/
class SomeOption{

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Module\Model\Client")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="job_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * */
protected $job;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false) 
 */
protected $option;



}
```

Bought model have getter and setter, in Client model have:

```
    public function addSomeOption(Collection $options) {
    foreach ($options as $option) {
        $option->setJob($this);
        $this->someOption->add($option);
    }
    return $this;
}

public function removeSomeOption(Collection $options) {
    foreach ($options as $option) {
        $option->setJob(null);
        $this->someOption->removeElement($option);
    }
    return $this;
}

public function getSomeOption() {
    return $this->someOption;
}
```

Form:

```
$this->add(array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
        'name' => 'someOption',
        'attributes' => array(
            'id' => 'someOption',
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Rozliczenie',
            'value_options' => array(
                array('value' => '1r', 'label' => '1/rok'),
                array('value' => '1m', 'label' => '1/miesiąc'),
                array('value' => '1w', 'label' => '1/tydzień'),
                array('value' => '1d', 'label' => '1/dzień'),
            ),
        ),
       'attributes' => array(
            'class' => 'span12 settlement chosen',
            'multiple' => 'multiple'
        )
    ));
```

after this i need have 1 row of client and 1+ row of someOption, may any help to repair code ? or much more will be explain what i make wrong.